# Why doesn't IE7 like this script?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

http://www.iamsolutionstv.com/widget/widget_dev.php

If you view-source on this page, you'll see that it's just a handful of javascript functions and jQuery calls, but IE7 refuses to behave - - - - it won't render the widget - - -whereas all the other browsers seem to draw the main video element, the playlists underneath just fine.  I don't get an error-message, which is what's really weird.  I've also run this javascript through JSLint.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.  I'm thinking there must be a debugger for IE7 that's useful for this type of thing.

Comment: What are the errors?  Where is your reproducible test code with the problem narrowed down as far as you can get it?  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: If the code works in most browsers but doesn't in IE7, then it wouldn't be a syntax problem that jslint could pick up, it is (most likely) a compatibility problem with IE7's JS engine. You are most likely using a function that IE7 doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

has nothing to do with script, when I turn off `overflow:hidden` on main "widgetspace" element in IE7 console  all your html is there.

Look at layout tab in console, height gets set at 31px in IE7...you just have css problems

Answer (score 0):

I used the Script Debugger for IE7 and could not see and script error. It looks like there is some css error with displaying your content.

Answer (score 0):

The script works, but not display on the page. Something is wrong with you style sheet.

The div#widgetspace is float to the left. But the div#thumbarea 's float is 'none' and the a tag's position is 'absolute'. Some browers(as IE6, IE7) donot work well.

May it helps for you!